# Why is the conditional probability treated as a definition in Kolmogorov's probability theory?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, definition

The conditional probability is defined as:

$$P(A|B) = \frac {P(A \cap B)} {P(B)}$$

given that $$P(B) \neq 0$$

This is achieved based on our intuition, along with the Venn diagram description of the sample space $\Omega$, the event $A$, the event $B$ and the intersection of $A$ and $B$.

My question is: why can't we treat the conditional probability as the corollary of the axioms of the probability theory, instead of treating it as a separate definition? Additionally, based on this point of view, it is seen that the Bayesian rule is almost as trivial as a definition.

My takeaway is, for any event $X$, defined on the probability space $(\Omega, \sigma, P)$, $P(X)$ could always be defined as a conditional probability:

$$P(X) \equiv P(X | \Omega)$$

Am I on the right track, or am I missing something important? Thanks!

Comment: Well you could first define a restriction $(\Omega, \sigma, P) \to (B, \sigma', P')$ where $P'(A) = \frac{P(A)}{P(B)}$ and $\sigma' = B\cap \sigma$. Then $P(A|B) = P'(r(A))$ where $r:\sigma\to\sigma', A\mapsto A\cap B$ is the natural restriction, but that's very clunky and still requires some form of a definition.

Comment: Interesting. So, you are basically asking why should we not define conditional probability as the most basic form of probability, so that the current definition of conditional probability comes out as a some lemma or theorem. This will probably require some notion of conditional measures. Most likely what might happen is we will end up pushing the current conditional probability definition and generalize it to general measures (if that is possible). So, we won't be able to get rid of the intuitive definition. Also, I can't see any particular advantage of a general conditional measure.

Comment: @AlexR Yes I indeed need some new definition. I am wondering if the new definition could only be $P(A|\Omega) \equiv P(A)$, so that $P(A|B) = P'(A')$ is defined on $(B, \sigma', P')$, where $\sigma'$ and $P'$ need no new definitions. It seems that $A' = A \cap B$ should be a trivial consequence. I am not about $P'$.

Comment: @TenaliRaman  please see my comment above - I am not sure whether we really need to define any new (or: conditional) measure $P'$, or it could be a corollary following the definition $P(A|\Omega) \equiv P(A)$ (on space $(\Omega, \sigma, P)$)?